# react-native-calendars customize

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to customize my calendar like this calendar:

[image: I want to customize my calendar like this calendar]

This is my calendar:

[image]

I want to customize my react native calendar:

```
<Calendar
        onDayPress={(day: any) => {
          setSelectedDate(new Date(day.timestamp));
          handleChange(selectedDate.toISOString());
          console.log(selectedDate.toISOString());
          setShowCalendar(false);
        }}
        
        //  disable prev month
        minDate= {new Date().toISOString()}
        disableAllTouchEventsForDisabledDays 
        /// disable date 
        markedDates={markedDates}
       
        
    />
  const markedDates = {
[selectedDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)]: {
  selected: true,
  selectedColor:  '#007fff',
  
  },
};
```

I want to customize selecday background, now is circle I want a square, also I want to give background color grey to change to square like this calendar. Can you help me?